# Delphi - Soap timeout have a maximum range?

Tags: delphi, soap, timeout, delphi-xe, soap-client

Im setting the timeout with 50000, but the exception throws with 42 seconds.

Setting with 10000, exception throws with 9,.. seconds.

Setting with 120000, exception throws with 42 seconds again.

```
  if FTimeOut <> 0 then
  begin
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
  end;
```

Soap timeout have a maximum or mininun range?

Comment: We need more info. What Delphi version and what internet components are you using?

Comment: What does the provided code have to do with SOAP? Windows doesn't throw exceptions for expired timeouts, so where are your exceptions coming from? And how are you measuring elapsed time?

Comment: ... and what type is FTimeout? Just asking.

Comment: The exception is from my application cant connect with server. Delphi XE. im using wininet dll... i founded a topic that explain a bug in InternetSetOption timeout, i think thats is my case...